# Nuxt 2 client Domain/network IP

Tags: web, nuxt.js, ip

I'm running a NUXT 2 web application.
The clients have a additional API running on there PC's, meant to run local installed programma's, like open certain file directly in that correct program.

The Nuxt server contacts the clients API by a fixed ip, hard coded in the server.
Send the filelocation to that static ip and the clients sees the magic happening...

What if the user moves to an other pc, logons in with his credentials, but then the file opens on his other pc... or not...

How can i get the current ip from that user, how can I tackle the problem described above.

thanks for your help